# How to launch correct version of Msbuild

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

When I type...

```
Msbuild<Enter>
```

...at the command prompt, I get...

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 2.0.50727.4927
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.4927]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2005. All rights reserved.
```

This is all very well and good except that when I run this against a Visual Studio 2010 `.sln` file, the error message indicates:

```
MyProject.sln(2): Solution file error MSB5014: File format version is not recognized.  MSBuild can only read solution files between versions 7.0 and 9.0, inclusive.
0 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)
```

It would appear that the version of MSBuild that is being called, is not capable of understanding my solution file.

I figured that I would check out my path and see where MSBuild is being picked up from. However, it seems that no part of my path points at a location where MSBuild is to be found.

How is the command line finding the copy of MSBuild that it is using and how can I change this version so that the latest version is used?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It must be somewhere in the PATH environment.  Use 'where msbuild' to determine where it is loading msbuild from.

Use the Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010) shortcut to initialize the path and other environment variables for VS 2010 and MSBuild 4.0.

Comment: As predicted... I had C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ in my path, but was essentially blind to it. Thanks.. the Where comand is something I've never seen before... great call

Comment: Don't forget, older MSBuild versions are also updated when newer .NET frameworks are installed.  For example, .NET Framework 4.5.1 also updates the .NET Framework 4.0 MSBuild version to 4.0.30319.18408.

Answer (score 42):

I found this question as my `PATH` variable did not contain a reference to `MSBuild.exe`. In case anyone else is having this issue, my resolution was to explictly register the environment variables for Visual Studio tools from the command prompt:

```
"%VS100COMNTOOLS%"\\vsvars32.bat // VS2010 environment variables
"%VS110COMNTOOLS%"\\vsvars32.bat // VS2012 environment variables
"%VS120COMNTOOLS%"\\vsvars32.bat // VS2013 environment variables
```

`MSBuild.exe` is now registered in `PATH`

```
where msbuild
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, these scripts are great to set the correct system path to MSbuild! Exactly what I was searching for.

Comment: This is the only way I could get it to work. vcvarsall.bat adds the old stuff to the PATH first.

Comment: This is the correct way if you want to emulate the visual studio build, as nowadays the .NET msbuild and the visual studio msbuild are separated. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2013/07/24/msbuild-is-now-part-of-visual-studio.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Change your [environment variables](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519).

Find/set your MSBuild **path** variable to be `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`

Obiviously the above path will depend on your installation location, but it will be close if not exact.

Comment: So you mean add `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` to the `PATH`-Variable of the System?

Answer (score 1):

For building a C# 6 project, this worked for me in a batch file

```
if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\14.0\bin" set MSBUILDLOCATION=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\14.0\bin    

if exist "%ProgramFiles%\MSBuild\14.0\bin" set MSBUILDLOCATION=%ProgramFiles%\MSBuild\14.0\bin

"%MSBUILDLOCATION%\msbuild.exe" "path\to\my\project.csproj"
```

You can easily change the version number (14.0) or add lines with more version numbers (12.0 and 4.0 for example) if you wanted to support a range of versions.