# Building Visual Studio Express 11 project from command line

Tags: c++, visual-studio, continuous-integration

So far, I had the following technique to build my C++ projects from the command line (purpose: nightly build with jenkins, with the same configuration as the 'normal' project) :

```
devenv MySolution.sln /build "Release" /project "MyProject"
```

or, from an express version:

```
VCExpress MySolution.sln /build "Release" /project "MyProject"
```

Now, I recently got VC11 express for Desktop, and apparently, it's not the same executable (I think the equivalent to VCExpress.exe is WDExpress.exe, am I wrong?), it's not the same command line (it's something like WDExpress MyProject.vcxproj /Build), and the build logs aren't outputed to stdout (they might be available elsewhere).

So, I'm just wondering if I'm missing something?

Maybe it's not WDExpress.exe that has to be called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue myself just now. I think we are supposed to use msbuild.exe itself. It's also a more general approach, since you don't have to switch between vcexpress and wdexpress. I'm not even sure wdexpress.exe supports building sln files anymore (from the command line)

Anyway, here's info on msbuild.exe
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662426.aspx

Tried it and it works. The location of msbuild.exe on my machine:
`Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe`
It obviously varies with the .net version, so I'm now looking for a way to get the path to msbuild.exe from an environment variable or something similar.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that one.. at least it's better documented than WDExpress (I found the "/Build" command in the Devenv.exe documentation, not in WDExpress.exe documentation). For setting the correct paths for MSBuild, does vcvars32.bat work? I used it to set the path to devenv and VCExpress...

Comment: i don't think you need to call the vcvars32.bat file. Since msbuild automatically builds the sln file with the correct Visual Studio version/edition, i think it automatically also sets the correct env variables.

Comment: as a followup, it turns out to be a good idea to call vcvars32.bat because it puts the msbuild path in the Path env variable:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12379822/911325

Comment: Ok, seems to be the tool for the job, but what is strange is that it seems to deliberately ignore some projects in the solution. For example, I have a target "doc" which launches Doxygen documentation generation. It runs perfectly from within the IDE, but MSBuild just says this target doesn't exist. It may as well be a problem coming from CMake... (I use it to generate VS projects).

Comment: seems to me like msbuild doesn't recognize the msbuild code generated by cmake. Or maybe you're not using the correct version of msbuild on your system. Sorry I can't be of more help, not really familiar with this issue. What you could do is open the solution in a text editor and look for your doc target. See what the correct msbuild syntax is for a target and see if the doc target follows it and looks right. Hit me up via skype, my id is EddieBytes, I can try take a look at it if you want.

Comment: Ok, I finally sorted out my problems by calling 'cmake --build' rather than MSBuild.exe. 'CMake --build' internally calls MSBuild, but it works (it has it quirks too, which I reported here : http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=13623). The good thing is that 'CMake --build' should work the same way whatever the OS/compiler is.

Comment: MSBuild is not more general. It does not support projects using custom tools, which use a form of IDE automation and requires the IDE to be launched.

Comment: Can you update your final answer? MSBuild to cmake, What are all the steps? thanks.