# ASP.NET Core 2.0 The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 project developed using VS2017. I am getting the following error from our build server which uses TFS2015.

**The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format, please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the  element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.**

I got this error when I initially setup the build, but after reading through various posts I resolved the issue by installing the VS2017 SDK and build tools on the build server. All well and good.

I have now added a unit testing project and getting the error again. I am also getting this warning.

**Warning MSB4078 The project file is not supported by MSBuild and cannot be built**

I get this error when the build attempts to build the solution file. I have installed the latest version of MSBUILD on the build server. What else do I need to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42509313/the-default-xml-namespace-of-the-project-must-be-the-msbuild-xml-namespace)

Comment: This is the same issue we the duplicate I link above. Your version of MSBuild on your TFS server is old and need updating.

Comment: I updated the version of MSBUILD on the build server. I got this error when I initially setup the build, but then resolved it by installing the latest version of MSBUILD. I've added a new project to the solution and now getting the same error again.

Comment: Then you probably need to tell TFS to use the correct version of MSBuild.

Comment: I can specify the MSBUILD version for projects (which I had already done) but the build is failing when building the solution. There doesn't seem to be a way of specifying the MSBUILD version for a solution - only for a project.

Comment: I don't have a TFS instance to test, but you should be able to specify which path TFS uses for the build tools. Either that or you need to do something else. I suggest Google!

Comment: For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32627038/1663001

Comment: I can build the projects one-at-a-time which isn't ideal but will at least provide a workaround until I come up with a more permanent solution.

Comment: @DomBurf, Do you mean it works fine to build the projects one-at-a-time when you specify the location of MSBuild 15.0, but not work for solution file? Have you try to add another ASP.NET Core 2.0 project to the solution rather than a unit testing project?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT That's exactly correct. I can build the projects one at a time by specifying the location of MSBUILD but cannot build the solution file. I haven't tried adding any other projects other than the unit testing one but I can I can try and see what happens